# How to use PHP variable in shell-scripts?

Tags: php, shell, curl

I want to send a file to a remote server in PHP. When I make the file name hard-coded, the following code works fine:

```
$output = shell_exec('curl -XPOST -F "file=@myfile.txt" http://135.195.42.168:6007');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Now I need to decide *"file=@myfile.txt"* dynamically. I tried the following:

```
$filePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'package/myzip_'.$owner_id.'.zip';
$name = basename($filePath);
$content = "file=@{$name}";
$output = shell_exec('curl -XPOST -F $content http://135.195.42.168:6007');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Unfortunately, the above code does not work. Any better suggestion, please?

Comment: Single quotes will print out `$content`, not the contents of the variable. Change it to double quotes.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks so much, @aynber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'package/myzip_'.$owner_id.'.zip';
$name = basename($filePath);
$content = "file=@{$name}";
$output = shell_exec('curl -XPOST -F ' . $content . ' http://135.195.42.168:6007');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

should work fine

as well

```
$output = shell_exec("curl -XPOST -F $content 135.195.42.168:6007");
```

note:

`'` in php tells php to not interpret whatever is between `'`

```
$x = 'HELLO';


echo "what you say when you are nice? $x"; //outputs: what you say when you are nice? HELLO
```

this wouldn't work with `''`

echo '\n'; //outputs \n

echo "\n"; //outputs a newline (not a 
 newline, but a carriage return)

generally I feel it's safer to use '' whenever possible. It's not only safer, it is generally more practical as well, because you can do

```
$output = shell_exec('curl -XPOST -F ' . str_replace('a', 'b', $content) . ' http://135.195.42.168:6007');
```

you don't have to, rereading your code, to scan all strings for maybe a hidden $

Comment: Also, $output = shell_exec("curl -XPOST -F $content http://135.195.42.168:6007"); works fine.